# How to pass argument in function?

Tags: php

i have function like this.

```
function load($name, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4){
    $this->$name = new $name($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4);
}
```

the `load()` method will load some class and set it as class `property` and the infinite arguments, depend in the class they assigned.

another example if i only set method `$this->load` with 3 argument, the this what will happen in the process

```
function load($name, $arg1, $arg2){
    $this->$name = new $name($arg1, $arg2);
}
```

it is possible do something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use combination of [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and the help of [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#74427) like this:

```
function load(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    if( !count( $args)){
        throw new Something();
    }

    $name = array_shift( $args);
    $class = new ReflectionClass($name);
    $this->$name = $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An easier way of handling this is to use an array for the `$arg` variables.  The other constructors dynamically called (`new $name()`) would then need to accept an array as their input as well, and you can simply pass through the array of parameters:

```
// Params in an array
$params = array(1,2,3,4,5);

// Pass into the load() function
function load($name, $params) {
   // And pass them through to the dynamic constructor
   $this->$name = new $name($params);
}
```

Comment: no. can't use array. since the class `$name()` maybe required two or more arguments for `__construct()`

Answer (score 2):

Unless you set default values on the arguments, you must pass in values when the function is called:

```
function load($name, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4){
load('x'); // fails, didn't specify args 1->4
```

but with defaults:

```
function load($name, $arg1, $arg2 = null, $arg3 = null, $arg4 = null){
load('x', 'y'); // works, args 2->4 are optional
load('x'); // fails, didn't specify arg1
load('x', 'y', 'z'); // works, args 3->4 are null.
```

There are other options - pass in option arguments in an array, or use [`func_get_arg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

```
function load($name) {

load('x', 'y', 'z') // not an error, use func_get_args/func_num_args to get the extras
```

Comment: what i want to achieve, it is can do infinite arguments.

Comment: That'd be the last option, then. Specify the mandatory arguments in the function definition, then use func_get_args() to all the 'infinite' extras.

Answer (score 1):

[func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) might be what you're looking for.  From the PHP Docs:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Number of arguments: 3<br />
Second argument is: 2<br />
Argument 0 is: 1<br />
Argument 1 is: 2<br />
Argument 2 is: 3<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to define a function with a truly variable-size arguments in PHP.  You need to use `func_get_args` function in your function:

```
function load() {
    $args = fnc_get_args();
    $name = $args[0];
    $arg1 = $args[1];
    ...

}
```

You'll need to then determine what/how to call next.